# Why the ownership of unique_prt is not transfered when using rvalue reference?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, rvalue

If I run the code

```
class Myc {
  private:
    int m{0};

  public:
    Myc(int ii) : m{ii} {};
    ~Myc() { std::cout << "Myc Destructed\n"; }
    int getM() const { return m; }
};

void foo(std::unique_ptr<Myc> other) { std::cout << "End foo\n"; }

int main() {
  std::unique_ptr<Myc> pm = std::make_unique<Myc>(1);

  foo(std::move(pm));

  std::cout << "End main \n";
}
```

the ownership of pm is transfered to foo and the output is

```
End foo
Myc Destructed
End main
```

but if change foo to

```
void foo(std::unique_ptr<Myc> &&other) { std::cout << "End foo\n"; }
```

the ownership of pm is NOT transfered to foo because the output is

```
End foo
End main
Myc Destructed
```

I have tried this in clang and gcc. Why the ownership of pm is NOT transfered to foo when using rvalue reference?

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<Myc> &&other` is a reference, not an object.  No move happens when you make a reference. `std::move` is really `std::return_an_rvalue_reference_to_the_passed_in_object`

Comment: Only objects can take ownership. In the second version, the parameter is a reference. Reference simply refers (is another name for) an existing object, so no ownership transfer can happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass `unique_ptr` (or any smart pointer) by value when you want to transfer ownership.

Passing one by reference doesn't change ownership, and if the function doesn't change the ownership, perhaps it doesn't need a smart pointer as an argument (a bare pointer is often better).

To answer your question more directly: when you pass by value, the formal parameter (`other`) is move-constructed from the actual parameter.  The move constructor is what transfers ownership.  When you pass by reference, however, the formal parameter is a reference to the existing object - no new object is created, so the move constructor never happens.